# Hadoop reduce concatenating current value with previous values

Tags: hadoop, reduce

I have this reduce function:

```
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<SortedMapWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();
    double sum = 0, i = 0;
    DoubleWritable val = null;

    SortedMapWritable tmp = values.iterator().next();
    strOutput.append("[");
    Set<WritableComparable> keys = tmp.keySet();
    for (WritableComparable mapKey : keys) {                    
        val = (DoubleWritable)tmp.get(mapKey);
        sum += val.get();
        if(i > 0)
            strOutput.append(",");
        strOutput.append(val.get());
        i++;
    }
    strOutput.append("]");

    context.write(new Text(key.toString()), new Text(strOutput.toString()));
    context.write(new Text(key.toString() + "Med"), new Text(Double.toString(sum/i)));
}
```

As SortedMapWritable, I used a `<LongWritable,DoubleWritable>`, as we can see at this code

```
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    final Context ctx = context;
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf); 
    Path srcPath = new Path(hdfs.getWorkingDirectory() + "/" + value);  
    Path dstPath = new Path("/tmp/");       

    hdfs.copyToLocalFile(srcPath, dstPath);

    final StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder();
    final Pcap pcap = Pcap.openOffline(dstPath.toString() + "/" +value, errbuf);
    if (pcap == null) {
        throw new InterruptedException("Impossible create PCAP file");
    }

    final HashMap<Integer,JxtaSocketFlow> dataFlows = new HashMap<Integer,JxtaSocketFlow>();
    final HashMap<Integer,JxtaSocketFlow> ackFlows = new HashMap<Integer,JxtaSocketFlow>();

    generateHalfSocketFlows(errbuf, pcap, dataFlows, ackFlows);
    final Text jxtaPayloadKey = new Text("JXTA_Payload");
    final Text jxtaRelyRtt = new Text("JXTA_Reliability_RTT");

    SortedMapWritable payOutput = new SortedMapWritable();
    SortedMapWritable rttOutput = new SortedMapWritable();

    for (Integer dataFlowKey : dataFlows.keySet()) {
        JxtaSocketFlow dataFlow = dataFlows.get(dataFlowKey);
        JxtaSocketStatistics stats = dataFlow.getJxtaSocketStatistics();

        payOutput.put(new LongWritable(stats.getEndTime()), new DoubleWritable((stats.getPayload())/1024));         
        HashMap<Integer,Long> rtts = stats.getRtts();
        for (Integer num : rtts.keySet()) {
            LongWritable key = new LongWritable(stats.getEndTime() + num);                                                      
            rttOutput.put(key, new DoubleWritable(rtts.get(num)));
        }
    }

    try{
        ctx.write(jxtaPayloadKey, payOutput);
        ctx.write(jxtaRelyRtt, rttOutput);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On reduce function, for each key, the value has been concatenated with the previous values.

For example, in the correct way, the keys and values should be:

key1 -> {a, b, c}     key2 -> {d, e, f}

But the values has been

key1 -> {a, b, c}     key2 -> {a, b, c, d, e, f}

Does anyone knows why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you show the contents of the reduce function or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your reduce function should concatenate all values with a "," in betweeen. So for input <5,<3,4,5>> it should generate <5,[3,4,5]> and <5,4> as output. That is not happening?

Comment: The problem is with values received by reduce fuction. 
for example, in case of two keys with three values each, the first reduce function receives three values, but the second functions receives the previous values and its expected values.

Comment: Can you post the code for `SortedMapWritable`, in particular the readFields method - i see people forget to clear the objects contents between calls to readFields and are always caught out by this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open bug with hadoop https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5454 that might explain the problem you are having.

In the following code, row.clear() is required to prevent the values appending from one iteration to the next.

```
@Log4j
public class StackOverFlowReducer extends Reducer
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        for (SortedMapWritable row : values)
        {
            log.info(String.format("New Map : %s", Joiner.on(",").join(row.entrySet())));
            row.clear();//https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5454
        }
    }
}
```

I only tested the workaround within a single key.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with the code you've presented for your reducer, though I would recommend refactoring its variable names to be a bit easier to understand.

We can only infer that your *Mapper* is passing these duplicate values on for each current key. This appears to be what's causing your duplication.

Comment: thanks, but the mapper is passing the values without duplications. In a example, the mapper writes a SortedMapWritable with size 3, and another SortedMapWritable with size 51, but the reducer receives two keys with size 3 and 54, respectively.

Comment: Are you using any custom partitioner or grouping comparator?

Comment: @ThiagoVieira Note that there are multiple ways for duplication to occur. The easiest is you're writing additional values to the same key accidentally. At what stage are you interrogating the output of your mappers?

Comment: At the mapper there is only one place where the keys and values are wrote, this is:
`ctx.write(jxtaPayloadKey, payOutput);
 ctx.write(jxtaRelyRtt, rttOutput);`. At this point, the cited example size of **payOutput** is 3 and the size of **rttOutput** is 51.